# Sprite dislplays all of the frames without acting like an actual sprite

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

So, i've been trying to make a videogame on unity, and i made my first sprite on piskel. Exported it as PNG but can't seem to make it work on Unity. I imported it as a new sprite and even selected sprite (2D and user UI) on the menu.[I selected 2D sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV7PH.png) but it doesn't work. It's just like if I put an image there, and not a sprite.[It stays still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEEcJ.png) I even tried using another sprite format [More rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwetx.png)

I can't find anyone else with the same problem out there on the internet, so help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting 2D sprite isn't the full story. You will also need to make the sprite "multiple" instead of "single" and split it up in the editor (now available in the package manager).

That will split it up into frames for you, then you drag and drop a single frame.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html